# How to extract the text within an HTML tag (in Selenium IDE)?

Tags: selenium

The html looks something like this:

```
<p>
    sometext1
    <br>
    sometext2
    <br>
    sometext3
</p>
```

I would like to extract all the text between the paragraph tags, including the `<br>` tags.

I tried to use `storeText` function, but it stores only the text, without the tags.
I could store the entire HTML source and then extract what I need in Perl, but I was wondering if there is a way to store a block of HTML code using a specific xpath (e.g. store the HTML code for the third table in the webpage inside a variable).

Answer (score 4):

innerHTML

i will try with document.getElementById('id').innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

you could use a getEval() with Javascript that return the innerHTML of the element. You'll have to find it in javascript, though

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. I'll post a more detailed answer later.

Comment: You could also consider marking this response as Right, if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

@Tarun: I would if I could man....

@Grooveek: Thanks man, that worked.
I used:

```
 storeEval | window.document.getElementsByTagName("p").item(9).innerHTML | p
```

This saved the content of the 9th paragrah in the variable `p`.
I had to use `getElementsByTagName` because the tags had no id's.

For more accuracy, one could use `getElementById` function insted:

```
 storeEval | window.document.getElementById("id of element").innerHTML | p
```

Hope this will help other people too.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
text = element.text
```

But keep in mind if you are dealing with text-boxes, you can't use `.text`; it returns `None`. In that case you should use `.get_attribute("value")`, and when ever you are unable to catch what you want, you can use `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`.

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute("innerHTML"); works for me

Answer (score 0):

I propose to find it by a class name, not all objects have it's Id.

```
storeEval | window.document.getElementsByClassName('*classname*')[0].innerHTML; | HTMLContent
```

number 0 will return first occurence. If there is more than one element, choose proper number, or get the number of class occurencies by .length

```
storeEval | window.document.getElementsByClassName('*classname*').length; | ClassCount
```